# помогите решить проблему Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

Вообщем он ругается на эту строчку странно, я не знаю почему присваивается значение null if (!responseStrings.TryGetValue(cultureInfo.Name.ToUpperInvariant(), out ImmutableDictionary strings))

```
private string GetString(string text, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    if (!responseStrings.TryGetValue(cultureInfo.Name.ToUpperInvariant(), out ImmutableDictionary<string, string> strings))
        return null;

    strings.TryGetValue(text, out string val);

    return val;
}
```

Comment: У вас через `out` пытается передать данные в `strings`, который скорее всего не инициализирован.

Comment: [Отладкой](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019) пользовались?